# paraview needs higher OpenGL in Mesa

Tags: qt, centos7, paraview, mesa

Im trying to use paraview 5.3.0 in CentOS.

I compiled it with Qt5. When I start paraview it tells me:

```
GL version 2.1 with the gpu_shader4 extension is not supported by your graphics driver but 
is required for the new OpenGL rendering backend. Please update your OpenGL driver. If you 
are using Mesa please make sure you have version 10.6.5 or later and make sure your driver 
in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2.
```

Here is the OnBoard graphics card:

```
lspci |grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Device 0536 (rev 04)
```

And the glxinfo:

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 256 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 17.0.1
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 17.0.1
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I dont understand what "... make sure your driver in Mesa ..." means.

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using llvmpipe/gallium with mesa, a software renderer, the OpenGL capabilities can be incorrectly detected. The simplest way to fix that is to force it :

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 ./bin/paraview
```

Comment: Im running this on hardware.

Comment: You may want to try this anyway.

Comment: @pwe Hi, I used this solution and it seems to work fine. Does it have any side effects or it works fine?

Comment: No side effects. You may want to specify the highest open GL version possible though.

Answer (score 0):

The **llvmpipe** is the software rendering driver.

I don't know if you are running CentOS on a VM or not (even if glxinfo says "OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc." that doesn't necessary imply you are running on VMware).

If you are not running CentOS as a VM guest, consider installing the appropriate mesa drivers for your video card.

Comment: Im running this on hardware.

Comment: Your video card appears to be a Matrix G200. That's a very old GPU and I doubt you can find any Opengl 3.3 compatible driver for it. You could override the OpenGL version used by llvmpipe as suggested by @Mathieu Westphal. Just be aware that this is going to be terribly slow...