# Python3 pip install vtk: OpenGL2 Error

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pip, vtk, pypi

I'm trying to install vtk via pip for Python 3.5.1 under CentOS 7.2. It seems to install and work with the system Python 2.7 instead. I get an OpenGL driver incompatibility error with Python 3.

I must use sudo. My attempts:

- sudo /path/to/pip3 install vtk
- sudo /path/to/python3 -m /path/to/pip3 install vtk

When executing a simple cylinder [example](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Python/GeometricObjects/CylinderExample/) Python 2 works properly. Python 3 error messaage:

```
ERROR: In /work/standalone-x64-build/VTK-source/Rendering/OpenGL2/vtkShaderProgram.cxx, line 446
vtkShaderProgram (0x169d500): 0:31(12): error: extension `GL_EXT_gpu_shader4' unsupported in fragment shader
```

glxinfo output:

```
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.6, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 10.6.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 10.6.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
```

I get the same error with Mesa 17.x. Has anyone installed this under Python 3 with success? What version of Mesa and/or llvm is compatible?

Comment: Is it possible to do `conda install vtk` instead?

Comment: Conda is not installed. I believe it may be a conflict with the sudo and user environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49878939/paraview-needs-higher-opengl-in-mesa) works.

```
MESA_GL_VERSION_OVERRIDE=3.3 /path/to/executable
```

I had tried this so many times with a manual install that I gave up on it. I've also seen [here](https://vtk.markmail.org/message/mksymlqg3lirkkil?q=mesa_gl_override) that this is a bad idea.

Edit:
I've had to crank up the override version number to 4.5 on other installs.